# Google appengine Java Document Search , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number of documents

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-search-api

I am using Google appengine document search functionality [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/)
I am trying to insert documents at batch of 20 by calling index.put() after 11 apis i.e 220 documents i am getting an exception. I also include simple exponential backoff strategy of 1 to 8 minutes when ever i get the exception, This approach will not scale for my problem. From google online docs the threshold for Maximum documents added or deleted is 15,000 per minute . I am trying to find out how to remove this restriction.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number of documents, 220, exceeds maximum 200
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.putAsync(IndexImpl.java:294)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.put(IndexImpl.java:497)

Answer (score 0):

The safety limits in the quota are there for protecting our customers (to make sure no rogue application consumes all the resources). Generally, using a back-off retry algorithm to control request intake is the recommended method for this issue.

If you have a strong business use case, you can either contact us directly (if you have a support package) OR report the issue on our [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) OR contact our [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) to work out a special agreement with them.

Comment: Thank you Ying Li,  I will raise issue in isure tracker to continue.